# Aggregating IEnumerable of Observables of T into one observable of T 

Tags: linq, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<Tourn>> collectionOfObservables
```

but i want

```
IObservable<Tourn> observableTourn
```

and I want all Subscribers of observableTourn to fire whenever ***any*** of the underlying observables change? need this in C#

Comment: When you have one `IObservable<Tourn>` there are no underlying observables. There is only one, in your case `observableTourn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Observable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229590%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use LINQ. The methods `Select` or `SelectMany()` will do the trick.

Comment: I get the following when i try using SelectMany The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I even tried casting no joy .SelectMany(x => (IObservable<Tourn>)x.Source);